# KVO's add & remove observer methods – counted or idempotent?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

In [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) I subscribe to receive change notifications from a potential sender with:

```
[potentialSender addObserver: self 
                  forKeyPath: NSStringFromSelector(@selector(aProperty))
                     options: 0
                     context: myKVOHandle];
```

And I can unsubscribe with:

```
[potentialSender removeObserver: self
                     forKeyPath: NSStringFromSelector(@selector(aProperty))
                        context: myKVOHandle];
```

Where KVO handles might be created with [this c idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28983215/2547229).

Are calls like these **counted** – so every `add` must be directly paired to and precede a `remove` – this is like the pre-ARC `retain` and `release`?

Alternatively, are they **[idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077412/2547229)** – any number of `add` calls can be stopped by a single `remove`, several `remove` operations without a matching `add` are safe?

---

I believe the idempotent approach is used for `[aControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]` <del>and also `[aNotificationCentre addObserver:selector:name:object:]`</del>. I was wrong about notification centre `addObserver` calls. They are **not** idempotent. However, removes are. Thanks to Rob for correcting me on this.

Comment: That `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(aProperty))` is kind of clever. I'd never seen that before, but it's an interesting way to avoid at least certain kinds of typos.

Comment: Same here - never occured to me that we could also use it for property accessors. Sweet!

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks! It gives some compile time safety and is also "refactor proof" for a rename. It is annoyingly verbose though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KVO calls must be balanced. Every `addObserver:...` must be balanced with an equivalent `removeObserver:...`. And there is no mechanism to "unsubscribe all" like there is for `NSNotificationCenter`. A remove that does not balance an add is an error. KVO is very picky.

Note that `NSNotificationCenter` is absolutely not idempotent. Multiple, identical `addObserver:...` calls will result in multiple notifications. It's just possible to do a global `removeObserver:self` without balancing every `addObserver:...`, and it is safe to remove when you have not added.

Comment: Super – thanks for answer and for clearing me up on notifications too – so, `removeObserver: self` is idempotent, but add isn't?

Comment: Correct. In any object that uses NSNotificationCenter, I always add an extra removeObserver:self in dealloc, just as insurance.